# Play Lottie animation with a different delay when in viewport

Tags: javascript, lottie

I want to play lottie animations in a section with a  delay when they enter the viewport - how would I do that?

I tried this code from the interacitivty lottie library but it didnt work:

HTML:

```html
  <lottie-player id="lead" src="https://lottie.host/9af8230c-e744-48d9-b2d4-1aff06e464b8/tykFOU2onq.json" background="#ffffff" speed="1" style="width: 100%; height: 50vh;" autoplay></lottie-player>
```

JS:

```css
<script>
LottieInteractivity.create({
    player: '#lead',
    mode: 'scroll',
    actions: [
        {
            visibility[0.1,1],
            type: 'seek',
            frames: [0, 300],
        },
    ]
});
</script>
```